# Python - Turn bytes object into tensor object for use in torch.load()

Tags: python, tensor

I have downloaded a `tensor` (.pt) object from my Google drive into my Python workspace, which is currently a `bytes` object. It needs to be a `tensor` object (X) to be used in the code `torch.load(X)`:

The code to download the tensorflow object from my Google Drive is:

```
file_id2 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id2)
gh = io.BytesIO()

downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(gh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
X = gh.getvalue()
```

I have tried to find a way of getting the bytes object (X) into a tensor object, but I am not finding anything helpful

Is there a way of doing this? or a way of downloading the tensor object from google as a `.pt` file and not `bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it, so will leave this here in case anyone needs it in the future.

```
tensorObject = torch.load(io.BytesIO(X))
```

I had to pass the object as a BytesIO object (I thought it already was), and now it works :)